# Push Laravel collection in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3

I am new to `Lavarel` and I wrote this portion of code to add my collection to a javascript array and it does not seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var data = [];
            @foreach($products as $product )
                data.push({'{{ $product->id }}' : '{{ $product->name }}'});
            @endforeach

//            Im trying to get a variable which looks like this
//            data: [
//                {
//                    id: 'The ID goes here',
//                    text: 'Text to display'
//                },
//                // ... more data objects ...
//            ]
        });
```

Kindly help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to create a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) and convert this to json so javascript can read this.

```
var data = {{ $products->map(function ($product) { return ['id' => $product->id , 'text' => $product->name];})->toJson() }};
```

It would be even cleaner to generate this json string in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just convert the collection to JSON in your Laravel Controller:

```
$collectionArr = Collection::all()->toJson();
```

Then echo it out in the HTML:

```
<script>
    var jsArray = {{$collectionArr}};
</script>
```

Here's more info from the Laravel Site:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var data = {!! json_encode($products) !!}; // Note the {!! !!} to not encode html entities since we'll probably have quotes in here                 
});
```